# How can I add no-follow to all links in a WordPress site in one go?

Tags: wordpress

I'm coding a WordPress website in which I want all the external links to be "no-follow" by default.

It is quite long to go and edit each single link to add the "no-follow", is there a way to code it once for all?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the best way to do so is using **a custom filter**. Being generated dinamically by PHP, you can edit links on post and pages server-side even *before* a user visit them: WordPress used to add `rel="nofollow"` to each link by default in the past, but I see it doesn’t happen anymore. Then, I found [a solution by **Debjit Saha**](https://www.isitwp.com/nofollow-external-links-only-the_content-and-the_excerpt/) you may try on `functions.php`.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_nofollow');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'my_nofollow');

function my_nofollow($content) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/<a[^>]+/', 'my_nofollow_callback', $content);
}

function my_nofollow_callback($matches) {
    $link = $matches[0];
    $site_link = get_bloginfo('url');

    if (strpos($link, 'rel') === false) {
        $link = preg_replace("%(href=\S(?!$site_link))%i", 'rel="nofollow" $1', $link);
    } elseif (preg_match("%href=\S(?!$site_link)%i", $link)) {
        $link = preg_replace('/rel=\S(?!nofollow)\S*/i', 'rel="nofollow"', $link);
    }
    return $link;
}
```

Please, notice that [some plugins could break this code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223970/nofollow-external-links) and I’ve never tried this on newer WordPress versions.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is using JavaScript:

```
var hrefToCheck = "mysite.com" // change this string

noFollowExternalLinks(hrefToCheck); // call to run the function below

function noFollowExternalLinks(siteHref) {

  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(link) {
    if (!link.href.includes(siteHref)) {
      link.setAttribute("rel", "nofollow");
    }
  })

}
```

So, you can change `hrefToCheck` variable to a piece of your site URL that will be checked inside each link inside the page.
The function will loop to check every link in the page and apply `rel="nofollow"` to all external links (that don't match the text in the variable).